# How to set County Vise Tax in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to have magento store running in Nevada USA, Nevada have different sales tax rate for different counties, please see [this URL](http://tax.nv.gov/uploadedFiles/taxnvgov/Content/TaxLibrary/TPI-01.07%20Sales%20Tax%20Map_07-01-12.pdf)  for tax rates.

To achieve this, I have done below things

1. Setup Tax Zones and Rates (SALES >> TAX >> Manage Tax Zones & Rates)
2. Setup Product Tax Class (SALES >> TAX >> Product Tax Classes)
3. Setup Customer Tax Class (SALES >> TAX >> Customer Tax Classes)
4. Imported Tax Rates (SALES >> TAX >> Import / Export Tax Rates)

[here is the](http://www.screencast.com/users/mack5124/folders/Default/media/ecadb13e-a638-4980-b8d0-523566caf459) screenshots for TAX ZONES & RATES SETUP and tax rates in CSV

The Issue is this setup is not working, it works for only last zipcode of county in CSV sheet.

Please help me if anyone have any idea

Answer (score -1):

You can check [Magento Cigar Tax Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cigar-tax-manager.html) extension that allows admin to set Taxes on product categories at State, County, City levels.

It calculates / sum-up Tax value on each product/category in the cart based on State, County, City entered in shipping address by a customer.

If a product is assigned to category which is not assigned any State/County/City Tax values, in such cases, that product will be assigned with default tax values.